# How to create a new form and put a button on it?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have just downloaded Visual Studio 2012 Express, I have created a new Win32 project on C++ and I can't find where find the form so I can add some controls to it using the IDE exactly as I used to do in C#!

Could someone please help me on how to add a Form and Some controls on it using the IDE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create forms for native C++ applications by GUI. You have to either use `MFC` or `C++/CLI`, or stick to C#. Unfortunately, GUI applications creation in pure C++ isn't very easy.

You could also take a look at Qt Creator - although I don't like it personally, it might be just what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a .rc file to your solution, and then from resource view add a new Resource. Then you can work with the toolbox, I hope that helps.

[image: Visual Studio resource editor]